# MySQL: How to get specific row using column value?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to get a specific row based on a columns value?

Say I have a column 'name' which has a unique value and I want to get an entire row based on that single value. For example, say I have a row defined by three columns 'name' 'city'  and 'state' and want to get all three columns associated with that row only using the value 'Jeremy' found in the 'name' column.

I know I can do this by selecting all rows and use if statements to break down the rows to find what I am looking for but I am also sure there must be an easier command through MySQL to achieve this.

Comment: Time to open up your MySQL book or read through the documentation - this is very basic stuff!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it as simple as this? This is a basic filtering :D

```
SELECT name, city, state
FROM tableName
WHERE name = 'Jeremy'
```